# Is this a good way of separating graphics from game logic?

Tags: opengl, c++, architecture

My current architecture for me game engine looks like this, though it is not accurate:

[image: diagram]
Everything graphics related is done in by `GraphicsEngine`, and through its components, like `Material`, `Mesh`, etc). My problem is that I want to store the pointers in `RenderData`, but I have to include the `Mesh`, `Material` etc header files, which have included `glew`.

I currently change an objects material using `GetRenderer().SetMaterial("xyz")`, which sets a string in the `renderData`, to be processed by the graphics engine; then the correct pointer will be set, if it exists. This is not so modular, because the scene has graphics related files included, like `glew`. This is a problem.

My only solution is to store indices in `RenderData`. There wont be a material pointer, but instead, an index where the material is in the `GraphicsEngine`s material store. This way, `RenderData` is just a "blind" integer and string store, in which the Renderer egy the `GraphicsEngine` works.

Is this a good solution?

---

Meshes have `VertexData` members (position, normal, texture). When I call `GraphicEngine.CreateMesh()`, passing the `MeshName` and `FileName`, where should the file processing go? I use Tiny Obj Loader, and I don't know where I should include it, and call its function.

I call the function from inside `GraphicsEngine`, then I transform the returned structures to my Mesh's structure, which I pass to the Mesh's constructor. The initialised list will assign it to the corresponding member variable. Inside `Mesh`, I pass the `FileName` to the `Mesh` constructor, and let it handle it all by itself. I think the first solution is better, but I don't really know why.

Maybe using `GraphicsEngine` to "create" assets is better than `GraphicsEngine` commanding assets to "be created"; but this is just a personal feeling. Which solution is better?

Comment: To solve your 'include' concerns, did you look into the pimpl idiom, where the classes only expose their public interface (they're actual pure virtual classes, or interfaces), and another class takes care of the implementation, including the storage of the data. This way you don't have to expose internal types.

Comment: I feel like this question asks "is my way good? Why, why not? What are better ways?", which teeters the fence between too broad and opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is only perfect if it does everything you want it to do. If you've ever made a game before, then you'll realize that nothing is perfect based on this statement, because nothing satisfies all your needs.

Now that that's out of the way, let's speak about your current approach and a different approach to solve some of your problems.

If I understand your solution correctly, then it succesfully provides a layer of abstraction over the rendering library. If this means, that you only need to include some OpenGL headers to communicate with the library, then it's fine. Gameplay programmers aren't completely incompetent, they know how to include a simple header, even if they don't know what it's used for (and even if they don't, the IDE can do that). Some rendering engines (like LibGDX) still make the programmer use OpenGL functions to do some things (like clearing the screen). However, if you're able to abstract every piece of OpenGL and anything related to rendering away from the core library, then that'd be even better.

Here comes in the event pattern. Instead of relying on components, this pattern uses completely separate objects  managed by a core class and the communication is handled by messaging.

When you for instance need to render something from the core gameplay object, then instead of telling the renderer directly to do it, you just create a small data structures containing the request, put them it a container and let the other objects read it. The renderer should take this message out and complete the request. It's similar to a bulletin board. Someone posts their request, someone else finds it, takes it and completes it.

There are multiple pros to this pattern. First of all, it's completely modular. Nothing should break if you add or remove an event reader. This way if the renderer fails, then the event handler manager class can save the players progress and turn the game off safely, instead of it pulling the whole game with itself. You can also change the components if you for example change your mind and start using DirectX instead of OpenGL.

There is one big con I can think of, and that is flexibility. If you want to make every single operation possible through messaging, then you'll need to create a protocol. For example, the rendering part should take every event, that has the headers "render", "change_material" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Indices is a good way to solve the problem as long as the `Scene` does not have to change any of the data, in which it can become quite tedious, I would even suggest actually moving the `RenderData` object to the `GraphicsEngine` and just keep an index to it in the `Object` instead.

One reason why it is good to use indices, is that you can handle memory more efficiently because it is easier, for example, to put the meshes after each other in memory which means access to them gets quicker, also you can move the data around in memory more easily. Another reason why indices are a good idea is that `Scene` gets completely agnostic for how the meshes etc. work and they can be changed without it affecting the scene in any way as long as something that does the same exists at the same index.

On the second question, I would suggest having a `MeshFactory`, a separate object dedicated to creating meshes. Having a separate factory would be good because you can more easily keep track of which files you have loaded so you don't load a file twice and also it makes it so that the `GraphicsEngine` does not have to know how the mesh loading works, only how your mesh class works and how the factory works which makes it easier to change the loading to support, for example `.fbx` files.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare only pointers of `Mesh` etc. in `RenderData`'s header file, I think you can use forward declaration for them?

And to let `RenderData` store ints and strings is not a good/bad thing, I'd rather to discuss if it's suitable. And if it's designed to overcome the include thing, I don't think it is.

---

For the `Mesh` creation question, I think to let `Mesh` handle the Tiny Obj is better, i.e. I think to let `GameEngine` command the `Mesh` to be created itself is better. Just think `GameEngine` as a general, and `Mesh` etc. are soldiers. The soldiers should be responsible for firing bullets, reloading etc., the general just give the order when needed. If the general has to retrieve the bullets from the armory and replace the clip for the soldiers then it would be too much isn't it?

I know sometimes it's difficult or vague to see which responsibility belongs to the "objcet manager" or "object", but I think the "object"s should at least have some ability to take care itself. For the `Mesh` and `GameEngine` architecture again, the inner implementation like Tiny Obj should be taken care by `Mesh`. Since `GameEngine` is a rather large module, it shouldn't know such low-level details. Also if you encapsulate the details in `Mesh` then it's easy to replace or modify them, and you won't have to touch the `GameEngine` when you do so.